# LaTeX Error: Can not include graphics of type: pdf

Tags: graphics, pdf

Platform: TeXShop, version pi(?): 3.14159...1.40.9. on a Mac OSX, v.10.5.8.

The error I'm getting in `pdftex` is `Can not include graphics of type: pdf`

Oddly, my PDF graphic was originally included in a document that had no trouble formatting it (under same platform as above). I'm now trying to include this document as a chapter in a larger manuscript (different class) and am running into all sorts of errors. I have been searching the web and have overcome some of the errors but can't seem to find an answer to my current problem. Here is the basic framework of my document:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./graphics/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}


\begin{document}
...
\chapter{thebestchapterever}
\input{thebestchapterever.tex}
...
\end{document}
```

within `thebestchapterever.tex`, I have used the following code to include the graphic.

```
\begin{figure}
\noindent
\includegraphics[type=pdf, ext=.pdf, read=.pdf, bb=1.0in 1.0in 3.0in 5.0in, trim=2cm 7cm 2cm 10cm]{figurename}
\caption{...}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

I have also tried many combinations in `includegraphics`.  When I exclude the `type`, `ext` and `read` then it just can't find the graphic.  When I omit the `bb=` then I get a boundary boxy error.  If I add `.pdf` to `figurename` it doesn't help either.

All of these are new errors that didn't present in my prior work (for reasons that I'm guessing had to do with using a different class).

In addition `graphicspath` is no longer working either, so the figure needs to be in the same directory.

Any ideas on why my PDF is being rejected?  I would love some suggestions on a fix.

Comment: Your are using `pdflatex` and not (DVI) `latex` do you? Check or IDE/editor settings.

Comment: Try adding `% !TEX TS-program = pdfLaTeX` as the first line of your document.  This will ensure that  the `pdflatex` engine is used.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. I tried inserting this comment both before and after \begin{document} as I wasn't sure which was correct.  Neither worked.

Comment: I've closed this 'too localized' based on the comment on David's answer stating that the issue was an erroneous option given when loading `graphics`.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are using `latex` rather than `pdflatex` If classic `latex` is used with `dvips` then usually it can include EPS files but not PDF. If you use pdflatex the situation is reversed. that is why it is normally best to omit the extension. so each teX variant looks for the files that it can handle. `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}` declares that the system you are  using can handle those extensions, but if it can not, saying that it can doesn't help, and if it can, then the right extensions would normally have been declared already.

Comment: I am using pdftex (not sure if/how this differs from pdflatex?).  I know this because under the TexShop typeset menu, I have "pfdtex" selected and the first line of the console window  reads: "This is pdfTeXk, Version...."

It's odd because the same settings with my original document show no trouble in reading the pdf document!

Comment: Apparently, my reputation isn't good enough to post the answer yet, but here it is: "Just" user-error. ;-)

Prior to my package inclusion of

/usepackage{graphicx}

I discovered

/usepackage[pctex32]{graphicx}

The template-donor's usage of pctex32 doesn't apply for a mac. The problem was solved by a strategic insert of one character only: "%." Once I commented out the line with pctex32, the figure issue was no more.

Comment: glad you got it working. (I think that you are only barred from answering for a while as a new user)